# Problems trying out happstack-tutorial

Tags: haskell, happstack

I've been reading about Happstack and decided to give it a shot. I'm running xubuntu 9.10 and got to [this page](http://tutorial.happstack.com/tutorial/run-tutorial-locally) in the tutorial which told me to do `cabal install` in the tutorial folder. When I did this, I got the following errors:

```
$ cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure Crypto-4.2.1. It requires QuickCheck >=2
For the dependency on QuickCheck >=2 there are these packages: QuickCheck-2.1,
QuickCheck-2.1.0.1, QuickCheck-2.1.0.2 and QuickCheck-2.1.0.3. However none of them are available.
QuickCheck-2.1 was excluded because happstack-util-0.4.1 requires QuickCheck <2
QuickCheck-2.1 was excluded because MissingH-1.0.3 requires QuickCheck >=1.0 && <2.0
QuickCheck-2.1.0.1 was excluded because happstack-util-0.4.1 requires QuickCheck <2
QuickCheck-2.1.0.1 was excluded because MissingH-1.0.3 requires QuickCheck >=1.0 && <2.0
QuickCheck-2.1.0.2 was excluded because happstack-util-0.4.1 requires QuickCheck <2
QuickCheck-2.1.0.2 was excluded because MissingH-1.0.3 requires QuickCheck >=1.0 && <2.0
QuickCheck-2.1.0.3 was excluded because happstack-util-0.4.1 requires QuickCheck <2
QuickCheck-2.1.0.3 was excluded because MissingH-1.0.3 requires QuickCheck >=1.0 && <2.0
```

Is this telling me that some packages need <2 and others need >=2 ?

I tried to install both 1 and 2 via apt-get but it does not work. I get the same errors. If anyone can provide suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors of `happstack` are shipping a broken package.  As Ephemient points out, this is a [known problem](http://groups.google.com/group/happs/browse_thread/thread/e1cff6f1fbb543cc/13c03ffd4dcb7046).  Max Bolingbroke's message suggests a workaround.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/happs/browse_thread/thread/e1cff6f1fbb543cc/13c03ffd4dcb7046 Known problem, in fact.  Happs has only recently been updated for QC-2 support, and that hasn't been rolled out into a release yet.

Comment: This is still the case but it's getting better.

Answer (score 1):

Happstack 0.5 no longer requires any version of QuickCheck by default. If you opt to build the tests, then it uses QuickCheck 2.